# How can you prevent users from taking screenshots in a React Native IOS app?

Tags: ios, react-native, screenshot

I am currently building an IOS app with React Native, and I am looking into how to prevent users from taking screenshots on certain parts of the app.

I read this article on this issue: https://www.netguru.com/blog/prevent-screenshots-react-native, and I learned that there are basically two options. I can either use the paid ScreenShieldKit SDK or I can create an invisible screen animation that somehow covers the content of the app in a screenshot.

I am not looking to pay for ScreenShieldKit, so how can I go about making this animation to cover screenshots on my app, and will it even work?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[The two options for preventing screenshots on a React Native IOS App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6efJ.png)

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? Someone can take a picture of his phone with another phone or camera anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ScreenShieldKit's technology is patented. And more likely than not, it is based on the other solution which you yourself know of (invisible screen animation). So it may not be wise to post the exact code here, as it could very well infringe upon their patent.

Comment: It is actually based on DRM, not some screen animation which probably doesn't work. See https://daringfireball.net/2018/01/screenshield. To achieve something like ScreenShieldKit I believe is going to take _a lot_ of work.